# How do I get background shapes to position within a section down the page? - CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position several shapes around the background in my CSS, but can't figure out how to do it. It worked okay for my hero section - but that's at the top of the page. This one is halfway down the page and whenever I set 'absolute' on to the parent and 'relative' on the child, it positions the elements at the top.

For example, I want my first square to be 12% from the top and 23% from the left **within my section container**. I then want to position my other two at other random % points across the page.

Here' my code:

```css
.features-section {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.features-section li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}

.features-section li:nth-child(1) {
  top: 12%;
  left: 23%;
  background: #ffa299;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<section class="features-section">
  <ul class="features-animation-list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

The shapes will be li:nth-child(2) / (3) etc so I've only included the one.

Any pointers?

Comment: *" whenever I set 'absolute' on to the parent and 'relative' on the child,"* ....you have these the wrong way round .Parent=relative, child=absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.features-section {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative; /*Set relative postion to parent*/
}

.features-section li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute; /* Set absolute position to child*/
}

.features-section li:nth-child(1) {
  top: 12%; 
  left: 23%;
  background: #ffa299;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.features-section li:nth-child(2) {
  top: 12%; 
  left: 40%;
  background: #ffa299;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<section class="features-section">
  <ul class="features-animation-list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `position: relative` for the parents and `position: absolute` for the childs.  I made an example for you here:

```css
.features-section {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.features-section li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
}

.features-section li:nth-child(1) {
  top: 12%;
  left: 23%;
  background: #ffa299;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
}

.features-section li:nth-child(2) {
  top: 50%;
  left: 53%;
  background: #ffa299;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
}

.features-section li:nth-child(3) {
  top: 75%;
  left: 73%;
  background: #ffa299;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"> hello
</div> 
 
 <section class="features-section">
  <ul class="features-animation-list">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
```